# Unable to install the ipa into iPad1

Tags: ios

I am unable to install IPA on iPad1(IOS 5.1.1).
IPA is built using xcode 5.1 with follwing settings:
Architecures:standard architectures(armv7,armv7s,arm64)
valid Architectures:armv7,armv7s,arm64
Deployment target: 5.1.1

Please let me know what settings should be done so that IPA installation will work on IOS 5.1.1 , IOS 6,IOS 7.

Note:
Provisioning profile contains UDID of the iPad1.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Did you install the ProvisioningProfile onto your iPad separately?

Comment: Unclear information with question. what error. did you add device id of your developer cer. or not?

Comment: Not getting error. Its asking to retry installation

Comment: I searched on stackoverflow. Many told to remove arm64. But tn wl it work with other iPad devices?

Comment: use only armv7 Architecture....and check whether your device UDID is added or not in  distribute profile.

Comment: did you change your deployment target to 5.1.1 in your `project` _and_ `target`'s?

Comment: Yes. I have added UDID in distribution profile. And also set deployment targets in project and target.

Comment: If i use only armv7, will it work on all devices for all versions?

Comment: try to use armv7, armv7s architecture for `debug`, but arm64, armv7, armv7s for `release`.

Comment: refresh your profiles and select valid profile...before creating ipa file.

Comment: Check the ipa is 32 bit. 64 bit is not supported prior to iOS 6 and will fail to install.You can see an error message for this behavior by dragging the ipa onto the Application node of an iPad running iOS 5 in Xcode.

Comment: Can you show the device log when you try to install the ipa there ?